# When Using Scanner.hasNextLine in a while, main method repeats indefinetly

Tags: java, multithreading

When using "scanner.hasNextLine()" inside of the thread, it causes my main method to repeat indefinitely.

Here is the code:

```
private static SerialPort port1 = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM5");
private static SerialPort port2 = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM3");

public static void main(String[] args){ 
    if(port1.openPort())System.out.println("Connected to Port 1 on COM5");
    else System.out.println("Could not connect to Port 1 on COM5");
    if(port2.openPort())System.out.println("Connected to Port 2 on COM3");
    else System.out.println("Could not connect to Port 2 on COM3");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(port1.getInputStream());
    Thread readThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                System.out.println("Has Next");
            }
        }
    };
    readThread.start();
}
```

I would also like to note that when I use "while(true)" I do not encounter this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `while(true)` does *not* loop indefinitely? Are you sure you tried that?

Comment: It does not force the main to recursively run like "scanner.hasNextLine()" does

Answer (score 1):

Modify your thread like this:

```
@Override
    public void run(){
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("Has Next");
            scanner.nextLine();//move to next
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does not help, it keeps repeating "Connected" still. Thanks anyway though